# How to use startActivity to open data uri

Tags: android, android-activity, data-uri

I want to open a data: url containing a pdf in an activity in my android application. I have something like the following code:

```
String url = "data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjIgDQol4uPP0w0KIA..."; // shortened for brevity
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```

I am seeing an error:

> error opening uri: No Activity found to handle Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=data:application/pdf... (followed
>   by the rest of the data url).

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since approximately zero apps in existence will support that scheme, you will need to decode the PDF yourself, write it to a file, and then open the PDF viewer on the file.

Comment: I also get the same error if I use a data url with the content type text/html. Does this mean there is no hope for using data urls in android?

Comment: @1800INFORMATION: You are welcome to find some third-party PDF viewers and Web browsers that support `data` URLs, then force users to install those to use your app. In the specific case of HTML, `WebView` in your own app might handle it (not sure, haven't tried it). But you cannot force, say, Adobe to support `data` URLs for Adobe Reader. `content://` and `file://` scheme support is solid (plus `http://`/`https://` for browsers and select other apps), but after that support for other schemes becomes far less common.

Comment: @1800INFORMATION: It's not out of the question that you could create your own little `ContentProvider` that handles the decoding for you and serves the PDF, avoiding having to write the content to a file.

Comment: ok thanks, I was just really hoping there was going to be a way to do it with data urls. I'll probably actually have to go back to the drawing board and write the pdf to a file

Answer (score 2):

You need to have an app that can handle opening pdf documents. If you still wish to do this catch an ActivityNotFoundException and tell the user to download one.

Comment: Adobe reader is installed, so if that doesn't support it I guess nothing would

Comment: that might work but I can't be sure since I;ve never used pdf's in Android